# Datatypes and quantifier patterns/triggers

Tags: z3

I observed a difference in Z3's quantifier triggering behaviour (I tried 4.4.0 and 4.4.2.3f02beb8203b) that I cannot explain. Consider the following program:

```
(set-option :auto_config false)
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)

(declare-datatypes () ((Snap
  (Snap.unit)
  (Snap.combine (Snap.first Snap) (Snap.second Snap))
)))

(declare-fun fun (Snap Int) Bool)
(declare-fun bar (Int) Int)
(declare-const s1 Snap)
(declare-const s2 Snap)

(assert (forall ((i Int)) (!
  (> (bar i) 0)
  :pattern ((fun s1 i))
)))

(assert (fun s2 5))

(assert (not (> (bar 5) 0)))
(check-sat) ; unsat
```

As far as my understanding goes, the `unsat` is *unexpected*: Z3 should not be able to trigger the `forall` since it is guarded by the pattern `(fun s1 i)`, and Z3 should not be able (and actually isn't) to prove that `s1 = s2`.

In contrast, if I declare `Snap` to be an uninterpreted sort, then the final `check-sat` yields `unknown` - which is what I would *expect*:

```
(set-option :auto_config false)
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)

(declare-sort Snap 0)

...

(check-sat) ; unknown
```

If I assume `s1` and `s2` to be different, i.e.

```
(assert (not (= s1 s2)))
```

then the final `check-sat` yields `unknown` in both cases.

For convenience, here is [the example](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/WW1P) on rise4fun.

**Q:** Is the difference in behaviour a bug, or is it intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion (not (= s1 s2)) is essential. With pattern based quantifier instantiation, the pattern matches if the current state of the search satisfies s1 = s2. In the case of algebraic data-types, Z3 tries to satisfy formulas with algebraic data-types by building a least model in terms of constructor applications. In the case of Snap as an algebraic data-type the least model for s1, s2 have them both as Snap.unit. At that point, the trigger is enabled because the terms E-match. In other words, modulo the congruences, the variable I can be instantiated such that (fun s1 I) matches (fun s2 5), but setting I <- 5. After the trigger is enabled, the quantifier is instantiated and the axiom

```
(=> (forall I F(I))  (F(5)))
```

is added (where F is the formula under the quantifier).

This then enables to infer the contradiction and infer unsat.

When Snap is uninterpreted, Z3 attempts to construct a model where terms s1 and s2 are different. Since there is nothing to force these terms to be equal they remain distinct

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug since z3 doesn't say `unsat` for a `sat` formula (or `sat` for an `unsat` one). In presence of quantified formulas, SMT solvers are (in general) not complete. So they sometimes answer `unknown` when they are not sure that the input formula in `sat`.

For your example:

a - It's normal that, with matching techniques, z3 does not prove the formula when you assume that `s1` and `s2` are different. In fact, there is no `ground term` of the form `(fun s1 5)` that `matches` the pattern `(fun s1 i)`, and that would allow the generation of the useful instance `(> (bar 5) 0)` from your quantified formula;

b - When you don't assume that `s1` and `s2` are different, you would not be able to get the proof too. Except that z3 probably assumes internally that `s1 = s2` when `Snap` is a datatype. This is correct as long as there is nothing that contradicts `s1 = s2`. Thanks to this and to matching modulo equality, the ground term `(fun s2 5)` matches the pattern `(fun s1 i)`, and the needed instance to prove unsatisfiability is generated.

Comment: Thanks. I understand why Z3 reports `unknown`, but I'm surprised that Z3 reports `unsat` in the case of datatypes: to do so it must trigger the axiom, but given the triggers, it shouldn't be allowed to do it - exactly because `s1 = s2` is not known.

Why would it be sound for Z3 to simply assume `s1 = s2`? This would unsoundly prune a proof branch (that of `s1 != s2`), which apparently is explored in the case where `Snap` is not a datatype. Moreover, If Z3 simply added the equality `s1 = s2`, then it should report `unsat` if I added `(assert (not (= s1 s2)))` - which it doesn't.

Comment: By the way, I clarified my problem description, since your answer let me to conclude that it wasn't clear enough before.

Comment: z3 will not assume that `s1 = s2` if you explicitly say
that `(assert (not (= s1 s2)))`. I've said in my explanation that
z3 assumes `s1 = s2` only if there is nothing that contradicts
the equality. `s1 <> s2` clearly contradicts the equality.

Comment: The reason why it is sound to add `s1 = s2` as long as there is nothing that contradicts it is that: if you find a model for some formula `F and s1 = s2` then, it's also a model for `F`. For your example (from what I understand), z3 finds a model when assuming `s1 = s2`, and before instantiating the quantified formula. But,the generated instance (thanks to matching modulo equality) conflicts with another assertion that has nothing to do with `s1 = s2`. It is not necessary to look for the case `s1 <> s2`: the input formula is `unsat`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I still don't see why Z3 - unexpectedly, at least with how I understand triggers - reports `unsat` in the case where `Snap` is a datatype, but `unknown` when `Snap` is an uninterpreted sort - which is the answer I'd expect in both cases. It could of course essentially be a "random seed effect" that affects internal heuristics, but it could also be a more systematic difference between datatypes and uninterpreted sorts that I am just not aware of.